# need help understanding UPDATE...FROM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

please help me to understand how the T-SQL's UPDATE FROM query works. the sample query below results in

```
value-inc, value-dec
value-inc, value-dec
value-inc, value-dec
value-inc, value-dec
value-inc, value-dec
value-inc, value-dec
```

i expected this:

```
null,        'value-dec'
null,        'value-dec'
null,        'value-inc'
null,        'value-inc'
null,        null
'value-inc', 'value-dec'
```

where am i wrong?
thanks
konstantin

```
declare @t table (s1 varchar(10), s2 varchar(10));

insert into @t
select null, null
union all
select null, null
union all
select null, null
union all
select null, null
union all
select null, null
union all
select null, null;

update @t
set s1 = x.s1, s2 = x.s2
from (select null as s1, 'value-dec' as s2
      union all
      select null as s1, 'value-dec' as s2
      union all
      select null as s1, 'value-inc' as s2
      union all
      select null as s1, 'value-inc' as s2
      union all
      select null as s1, null as s2
      union all
      select 'value-inc' as s1, 'value-dec' as s2) as x;

select * from @t;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Ben Robinson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702079/need-help-understanding-update-from/3702148#3702148), you need a common value between the two tables to perform the update in the way that you expect. I've updated your original example, adding an id column to your table. That id is then used as the join condition for the update as illustrated in the code below. Hopefully this example will make things clearer for you.

```
declare @t table (id int identity, s1 varchar(10), s2 varchar(10));

insert into @t
select null, null
union all
select null, null
union all
select null, null
union all
select null, null
union all
select null, null
union all
select null, null;

update t
set s1 = x.s1, s2 = x.s2
from @t as t
inner join (select 1 as id, null as s1, 'value-dec' as s2
            union all
            select 2 as id, null as s1, 'value-dec' as s2
            union all
            select 3 as id, null as s1, 'value-inc' as s2
            union all
            select 4 as id, null as s1, 'value-inc' as s2
            union all
            select 5 as id, null as s1, null as s2
            union all
            select 6 as id, 'value-inc' as s1, 'value-dec' as s2) as x
on t.id = x.id;

select * from @t;
```

Comment: Yes this would work, what puzzles me slightly is why not simply insert the values to begin with rather than inserting rows of nulls then updating with the values?

Comment: @Ben: I was assuming that this was a contrived example to illustrate a point rather than a real world problem. Otherwise you're absolutely right.

Comment: Ben, this is just a contrived example to demonstrate the problem that i am trying to solve. of course it makes no sense to do this in production.

Answer (score 0):

Update from just allows you to build up a set of joins to define what you want to update, in the same way that you select from. e.g.

```
update t1
set t1.SomeField=t2.SomeDield
from Table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

In your example it wouldn't really work because there is no way to join the subquery to the table variable.

Comment: thanks. this helps somewhat but it does update the table just not the way i expected so it seems that it were able to join the subquery to the table somehow. if what i have does not work, how can i populate my table with values from a subquery such as that in my example?